# what is the difference between $1 and "$1" in bash script?

Tags: bash

example

```
while [ -n "$1" ]
do
  something
done
```

can i write `$1` instead of `"$1"`? And what is the difference between 
`user=alexander` and `user="alexander"`? Thanks

Comment: The shell does substantially more processing on unquoted strings than on quoted ones (not just splitting them up on whitespace or characters in IFS, but also expanding each of the post-split components as a glob) -- and in 99% of cases that processing is undesired. Missing quotes are probably responsible for more [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) entries than any other single class of error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ var="two words"
$ function num_args() { echo "${#}"; }
$ num_args $var
2
$ num_args "$var"
1
```

The difference between $A and "$A" is how word breaks are treated with respect to passing arguments to programs and functions.

Imagine script that works on files (let's say moves them around):

```
$ cat my-move
```

```
#! /bin/sh
# my-move

src=${1}
dst=${2}

# ... do some fancy business logic here

mv ${src} ${dst}
```

```
$ my-move "some file" other/path
```

As the code stands now (no quotes) this script is broken as it will not handle file paths with spaces in them correctly.

(Following thanks to @CharlesDuffy)

Additionally quoting matters when handling glob patterns:

```
$ var='*'
$ num_args "$var"
1
$ num_args $var
60
```

Or:

```
$ shopt -s failglob
$ var='[name]-with-brackets'
$ echo $var
bash: no match: [name]-with-brackets
$ echo "$var"
[name]-with-brackets
```

Comment: Please avoid all-caps variable names in examples -- see fourth paragraph of the relevant POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, specifying that POSIX-compliant shells and tools will only modify their behavior in response to all-caps variable names, *and reserving names with at least one lowercase character for application use*. Following this convention avoids situations like `for PATH in */` and suddenly no longer being able to run external commands.

Comment: BTW, it's not just strings that can be split on whitespace or `IFS` characters where quoting matters. Run `set -- '*'` and compare `echo "$1"` and `echo $1`; or `shopt -s failglob; set -- '[name]-with-brackets'; echo $1` compared against the same with quotes.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you. Can I use your comments to expand my answer?

Comment: By all means do.

Answer (score 1):

The quotes act as a way to group the argument regardless of the presence of spaces or other special characters. By way of demonstration, here's a case where the two are materially different:

```
$ foo="bar baz"
$ sh -c 'echo $1' worker $foo
bar
$ sh -c 'echo $1' worker "$foo"
bar baz
```

In the above example we pass `$foo` without quotes, which passes `bar` as argument 1 and `baz` as argument two, but when we pass it with quotes it passes `bar baz` as argument 1.

So while you can write a variable without quotes (e.g. `$1`), it is generally best practice to wrap it in quotes, unless you are specifically looking for it to be potentially treated as several independent arguments.

Comment: Even if you *do* want a string's contents to be treated as several independent arguments, just leaving out the quotes will often not behave as desired; [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) goes into several of the ways this fails (and why other mechanisms, such as arrays, should be used instead).